# In Simulink, how can you plot a signal in one axis, and another signal in another axis (in a 2D graph, like a parametric curve)?

Tags: matlab, simulink

The title may not be accurate, so let me explain. As you know, in Simulink we can use a Scope to plot two real signals/functions `x_1(t)` and `x_2(t)` against time `t`. The resulting graph has one axis for `t`, and one axis for both `x_1(t)` and `x_2(t)`. For example, if `x_1(t) = sin(2*pi*t)` and `x_2(t) = 2 cos(2*pi*t)`, then the graph in the Scope from `t = 0 seg` to `t = 1 seg` looks like this:

[image: Plot of x_1(t) and x_2(t) against time]

The previous graph can be easily obtained in Simulink as follows:

[image: Simulink block diagram and plot of x_1(t) and x_2(t) against t]

However, what I want to show in the graph, is `x_1(t)` in one axis, and `x_2(t)` in another axis. An axis for `t` wouldn't be shown. It's like a parametric curve, where `t` is the parameter and the parametric equations are `x_1(t) = sin(2*pi*t)` and `x_2(t) = 2 cos(2*pi*t)`. This is how the graph should look like:

[image: Parametric plot of x_1(t) and x_2(t) where t is the parameter]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized that instead of using the Scope block, I have to use another one called XY Graph, which is located in the library, in section Simulink >> Sinks >> XY Graph.